# Function won't compile because of one semicolon and i don't know why

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C but am stuck on one function that won't compile.The function is designed to randomly generate two integers as separate parts of an array of structs, and as I can tell, it works fine, it just wont compile.
The error I get is for the first '}' 
error: expected identifier or '('
Here's the actual function code. I'd appreciate any help.

```
struct nost * rnote(int measueres, int measuretime);
{


    int lengths[16*measures];

    int n = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < measures; z++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        float one = 0;

        float num = 0;

        do
        {
            num = rand()%100 //makes sure the number is 1-100

           if(num < 5){ num = 1/1}   //5% chance of whole note
            else { if (num < 15) {num = 1/2;}   //10% chance of half note  
                else { if(num < 45) {num = 1/4;}    //30%chance of quarter note
                        else{ if(num < 65) { num = 1/8;}    //20% chance of eigth note
                                else{ if( num < 80) {num = 1/16;}   //15%chance of sixteenth note
                                        else{ if(num < 90) { num = 3/4 ;}   //10% chance of dotted half
                                                else{ num = 3/8;}}}}}}  //10% chance of dotted quarter
                                                    //however, because  a measure can only have so many beats,
                                                    //smaler note engths will end up more likely to happen at 
                                                    //at the end of the measure

            if((one + num) <= measuretime) // makes sure that there are not too many beats in one measure
            {
                one = one+num;
                lengths[n] = num;
                n++; //moves n up one so that next lenght is in next spot of array
            }

        }while(one != measuretime);

    }

    int arraylength = n; // takes size of lentgh ^^^^ array and puts it in 
                                                        // the note array

    int notes[arraylength]; //the  actual notes

    for(int y = 0; y < arraylength; y++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int x = rand()%100;

        if(x < 17){ x = 1;} // makes it more likely by 17:8 odds for 1,3,5,8 in scale to appear
        else { if (x < 34) {x = 3;}     /// than for 2,4,6,7 to appear
                else { if(x < 51) {x = 5;}
                        else{ if(x < 68) { x = 8;}
                                else{ if( x < 76) {x = 2;}
                                        else{ if(x < 84) { x = 4;}
                                            else{ if(x < 92) { x = 6;}
                                                    else{ x = 7;}}}}}}}


        notes[y] = x;

    }

   static struct nost all[1024];

    for(int u = 0; u < arraylength; u++)
    {
        all[u].note = notes[u];
        all[u].length = lengths[u];
    }

    all[0].arraylength = arraylength;

    return all;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should not call `srand` in a loop. That will reset the random number generation. Only call `srand` *once*, at the start of the program.

Comment: Now as for your problem. The compiler will tell you which line it detected the problem. If it's for a missing semicolon the actual location is probably one or two lines *before* what the compiler report. So start at the line the compiler reported, then go backward in the code to look for any line missing a semicolon. Even without the error message (*always* include the full and complete and unedited error message in questions about build errors!) I could find it very easily.

Comment: It also helps if you try to minimize the code, by commenting out parts until it builds. Then you should have narrowed it down and can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That MCVE could probably be narrowed down even further giving you the location quite easily. Furthermore don't try to put so much things on single lines, it makes it harder to find error like these, or nesting/scoping errors.

Comment: Voting close because this is `a simple typographical error` question.

Comment: remove the semicolon here `struct nost * rnote(int measueres, int measuretime);`

Comment: `if(num < 5){ num = 1/1}` is a problem

Comment: Your code will not compile with a definition for `struct nost`, or without consistent spelling for `measures`, or .... You won't be able to fix your code by posting a question for each error you encounter.

Comment: That `if-elseif-else` ladder's indentation hurts my eyes *so much*.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you started your function with:

```
struct nost * rnote(int measueres, int measuretime); { [....]
                   Extra Semi-Colon Before Body ~~~^
```

Comment: The real MVP. Gracias amigo.

Comment: @Jonahcat That's not your only error though. Don't try to write large chunks of code without building. Write a few lines, build, fix possible errors, repeat. And it will help if you have an editor or IDE which parses the code for you as it can help indicate errors by underlining the places where it finds problems. Makes it very easy to find errors such as yours.